# How do I remove "/" and "/i" in a returned string with gsub?

Tags: ruby, gsub

I have this line:`msg = "Couldn't find column: #{missing_columns.map(&:inspect).join(',')}"`

that outputs: `Couldn't find column: /firstname/i, /lastname/i`

Is there a way that I can use gsub to return only the name of the column without the "/" and "/i"? Or is there a better way to do it?

I've tried `errors = msg.gsub(/\/|i/, '')` but it returns the the first missing column with "frstname".

Comment: `/\/|i` I'm.... I'm not even sure what that is, but it's a glaring syntax error when I plug it into Ruby, not a valid substitution by any means. Are you sure that's *exactly* what you used as your regex?

Comment: I missed a symbol. Here is the actual line @errors = msg.gsub(/\/|i/, '')

Comment: In future you may wish to wait longer before excepting an answer. A quick selection may discourage some readers from posting an answer that you might prefer to the one you have already selected. Of course, you can always change your selecting but you can generally avoid doing that by just waiting longer (a few hours perhaps). There is no rush, just don't forget to select an answer if at least one is helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/\/|i/
```

Let's break this down. The `//` on the outside are delimiters, sort of like quotation marks for strings. So the actual regex is on the inside.

```
\/|i
```

`\/` says to match a literal forward slash. `\` prevents it from being interpreted as the end of the regular expression.

`i` says to match a literal `i`. So far nothing fancy. But `|` is an *alternation*. It says to match *either* the thing on the left or the thing on the right. Effectively, this removes all slashes *and* `i` from your string. You want to remove all `/` or `/i`, but not `i` on its own. You can still do that with alternation, provided you include the slash on both sides.

```
/\/|\/i/
```

You can also do it more compactly with the `?` modifier, which makes the thing before it optional.

```
/\/i?/
```

Finally, you can avoid the `/\/` fencepost shenanigans by using the `%r{...}` regular expression form rather than `/`.

```
%r{/i?}
```

All in all, that's

```
errors = msg.gsub(%r{/i?}, '')
```

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down for me, the solution worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Given that these appear to be case insensitive regular expressions meaning

```
missing_columns 
#=> [/firstname/i,/lastname/i]
```

In this case rather than converting them to strings and trying to manipulate them from there you can use methods that a `Regexp` already responds to e.g. [`Regexp#source`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Regexp.html#method-i-source)

`Regexp#source` - *"Returns the original string of the pattern."* It will not return the literal boundaries (`/`) or the options (`i` in this case)

```
missing_columns.map(&:source).join(', ')
#=>  "firstname, lastname"
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `missing_columns` contains an array of `Regexp`s. So you can use `Regexp#source` instead of `Regexp#inspect`.

For instance

```
msg = "Couldn't find column: #{missing_columns.map(&:source).join(', ')}"

pp msg # => "Couldn't find column: firstname, lastname"
```

instead of

```
msg = "Couldn't find column: #{missing_columns.map(&:inspect).join(', ')}"

pp msg # => "Couldn't find column: /firstname/i, /lastname/i"
```

Feel free to browse the documentation for [Regexp#source](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.2.0_preview1/Regexp.html#method-i-source).

hope this helps!